# products in catalogue dont match Shop by

Tags: magento-1.9

My website is
[www.micahome.com.au](http://www.micahome.com.au)

1. Catalog pages are not displaying the products.
2. Shop by - products are different from displayed products.
3. Price structure on product page shows error of 2 x $$ (how to fix)
4. Footer is missing

Answer (score 0):

1. Please select category is Active
2. At display settings, Select Anchor is "yes"
3. Reindex the data and clear cache. Then check